# MIPS printing string

Tags: mips

So here is the practice question:

Given the data segment below, write the code to print the string “Hello”

```
.data
     .asciiz    “A”
     .asciiz    “Hello”
.globl main
main:
```

What I wrote under main:

```
main:
lui $a0, 0x1001
addi $v0, $0, 4
syscall
```

The output I am receiving is "A", obviously it's because the lui address is wrong. My question is, how do I print "Hello". Do I increment the lui address? And if so, by what?

I have searched around for similar answers, unfortunately people are smart and use pesudo instructions, which I am not able to use.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I solved it by adding this line of code:

ori $a0, $a0, 0006 

Si there an easier way?

Comment: It looks like your memory is growing down instead of up. If so, `0x10010000 + 0x0005 (length of "Hello") + 0x0001 ('\0')` makes `0x10010006`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good practice to define labels and avoid using unknown constants as adresses in the code. Your code could be rewritten to

```
.data
     str1: .asciiz    “A”
     str2: .asciiz    “Hello”
.globl main
main:
    lui $a0, $str2
    addi $v0, $0, 4
    syscall
```

But to answer your question, ASCII `A` (`0x41`) takes a single byte, null terminating the first string takes another one, so that `Hello` *should* be two bytes above `A`. The problem here is that your compiler may try to align your data. Better check your compiler options to be completely sure.

Comment: /* I know its pretty old, but I still find this answer. */ I had a warning from MIPS 4.5 about wrong operand type for `lui`, it works however with `la $a0, str2`

Comment: @Ramiz yeah, different flavours of MIPS parsers seem to attach different meanings to the dollar sign

Comment: You also need to use ASCII double-quotes, `"`", not slanted Unicode double-quotes `“`.  And no, MARS doesn't align `.asciiz` like it does for `.word`; character data has alignof(char) == 1.  This print-string system call only exists in MARS/SPIM (and any other clones), so you should use syntax for them (like a classic Unix MIPS assembler, not clang or GAS.)